# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la imagen de una página web al hacer scroll?

Tags: javascript, html5, animación, adobe-muse

Estoy usando `Adobe Muse` y quiero hacer una página que cuando hagas scroll se produzca una animación. Esto se podía hacer en `Adobe Edge Animate` solo que ya no está disponible y se me ocurrió hacer como sprites y que en el momento de hacer scroll cambiara de uno a otro y se produjera la animación. He exportado todo a `html`. Quería saber cómo puedo hacer eso. Supongo que es en `javascript`.

Aquí la parte generada en `Adobe Muse` donde está la imagen:

```
<!--------------Bloque de la imagen que quiero cambiar------------>
 <div class="clip_frame ose_pre_init colelem" id="u7080">
<!-- imagen -->
 <img class="block" id="u7080_img" src="images/bbq0001.png?crc=294256661" alt="" width="654" height="696"/>
</div>
<!-----------Fin del bloque de la imagen---------------------->
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algún ejemplo del efecto que estás intentando conseguir?

Comment: Hola @Alvaro, esta pagina es en la que me estoy tratando de basar, espero y estar en lo correcto, aqui esta el link: http://mcwhopper.com

Comment: Interesante. Si quieres algo como esa página, va a hacer falta algo más que simplemente cambiar la fuente de la imagen. Parece que hay un canvas y que se controla el scroll con JavaScript (hay muchos elementos que cambian: tamaño, contenido, rotación... dependiendo de la posición en la página)

Comment: humm.....bueno, muchas gracias @AlvaroMontoro, investigare eso, si me surge otra duda me estare contactando por aqui :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

con *jquery* seria algo tan sencillo como esto (asumiendo *bbq0002.png* para el nombre de la segunda imagen):

```
<script>
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        $( "#u7080_img" ).attr('src', 'images/bbq0002.png');
    });
</script>
```

Puedes agregar esta porción de código en cualquier lugar, preferiblemente dentro de la etiqueta `<head></head>`

Comment: Gracias por la aportación @JorelC, por el momento no esta funcionando, tal vez es error mio :p, estaré viendo eso, gracias

Comment: Dale @CarlosOrtega , probado y funcionando. Intenta revisar los _ids_ del elemento _img_, borrar la cache, etc. Cuéntame si lo logras hacer andar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un tutorial de adobe muse para **hacer exactamente lo que comentas**, podrás descargarte incluso los archivos que usan para practicar mejor. Este efecto es conocido como parallax. (https://helpx.adobe.com/muse/how-to/scroll-effects-motion.html) Yo trabajo también con Adobe Muse y he probado el tutorial. Ya me dirás que te ha parecido @CarlosOrtega

Comment: Muchas gracias @MarcLemien pero ya encontre la solucion ademas de que mi meta era otro tipo de efecto de desplazamiento que es el de la animacion, el cual incluye un archivo .OAM, pero aun asi agradezco el apoyo! :D

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado la respuesta. Si la compartes beneficiarás a otros. Aun así dejo mi respuesta pues es bastante fiel a lo que pides. En tu pregunta no dices nada de OAM y con el ejemplo de mcwhopper.com el tutorial de adobe hace lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Cuando pueda  hacer que me funcione lo compartiré! :D, y esque tengo todavía problemas porque como mencione, adobe edge animate esta descontinuado, y pues recientemente encontré que en Animate CC podía exportar como .OAM, que es el archivo que me permite hacer las animaciones, solo que, por alguna razón no funciona, la animación se reproduce, pero el efecto que quiero no se realiza, investigue en un foro de adobe y no soy el único con el mismo problema, jaja, al parecer tendremos que esperar por una actualización, saludos! y muchas gracias!.

Comment: Por lo que tu dices en la pregunta yo entendí que estabas trabajando en adobe muse. Por eso mi respuesta.

Comment: Si, la pregunta solo era como la alternativa mas cercana que se me ocurrió  a lo de Edge animate, aun asi trabajo con muse, porque el producto de animate CC que es el .OAM lo agrego en adobe muse, saludos!